# Node.js requre not working as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have used Node and node express generator to generate node express code.
All worked fine, until I had to deploy ti to the server.

By default there are couple of files :

`.bin/www` ( there I have `var app = require('../app');` )

```
app.js
```

My hosting requires that i have name of server.js for my starting point.
Moved www and and renamed it to server.js

And now there is a structure:

```
server.js 
app.js
```

Now i get problem in line where i have require `var app = require('../app');`

I have tried to change it to

```
var app = require('app');
var app = require('app.js');
var app = require('./app');
var app = require('app/app'); --> with move of app to different folder
```

But without success.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what hosting is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

`var app = require('./app');`

Not prepending `./` in front of the filename indicates that you want to `require` a *module* instead of a file.

EDIT:

Try the following:

```
var path = require('path');
var app = require(path.resolve(__dirname, './app.js'));
```

More info on the __dirname global can be found [here](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname).

Comment: Tried that also, didnt mentioned :( 
var app = require('./app');
Again , not working, with error 
Cannot find module '/app.js'

Comment: I edited the answer to include the __dirname variable. Does this fix your problem?

Comment: Great this fixed the issue !